# const pointer to const data and c++ lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers, constants

I want to insert some elements to the list.
What I really want to do is to use "insert3" because it guarantee that the pointer won't change, and the data won't change.
But "insert2" and "insert3" give the following error, which "insert1" doesn't:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::list<int*> l;
    void insert(int* const a)
    {
        l.push_back(a); //works
    }

    void insert2(const int* a)
    {
        l.push_back(a);
        /*
        no instance of overloaded function "std::list<_Ty, _Ax>::push_back [with _Ty=int *, _Ax=std::allocator<int *>]"
            matches the argument list
        */
    }

    void insert3(const int* const a)
    {
        l.push_back(a);
    }

};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do not mix pointers with STL Containers! It is a very bad habit. It causes future subtle bugs, dangling pointers, segmentation faults, memory leaks and so on... This is C++. Use smart pointers instead. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer or use std::list<std::vector<int>> or something like that.

Comment: @Equalitiesofpolynomials thanks, this is interesting, but not in our course material.

Comment: @Equalitiesofpolynomials It all depends on why your using pointers.  It's actually very rare to want a smart pointer in a container; most of the time, pointers in containers are used for navigation, in which case, raw pointers are preferable.

Comment: The real question is, in fact: why `std::list<int*>`, instead of `std::list<int>`?  I can't think of any reason to every dynamically allocate an `int`, and navigating to `int` doesn't make much sense either.  (A secondary question is: why `std::list`, rather than `std::vector`?  I can think of only one good reason---iterator validity, and the nature of the question makes it clear that the OP isn't far enough advanced in C++ for it to be an issue.)

Comment: int* is only an example, I'm using a struct instead of int. And I'm using pointers so I don't have to call CTOR's all the time. Lists are way easier for this type of homework I need to do, and as you said iterators (and find, push, front etc) are just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

You should use a `list<int const* const>` as the type of `l` instead and then you can use any of your inserts including `insert3`.

### Long answer

By inserting into a `list<int*>` you attempt to convert your `int const*` (pointer to const int) to an `int*` (pointer to int).

Since you are *removing* the guarantee that you will not edit the target of the pointer, this is not implicitly doable. You may use a `const_cast` (or c-cast) if you really wish to do this, but usually casting away `const`-ness is a very bad idea (tm).

#### Why making the pointer itself `const` won't change a thing

If you use version 3 using an `int const* const` (const pointer to const int), you are not getting anything more or less than the guarantee that the variable `a` will not be changed while `insert3` is running. By inserting the pointer into your list, you are actually copying it. This means that no matter whether `a` is `const` or not, your resulting list item will be the type you specified in the beginning.

By making the list into `list<int const* const>` you ensure that any pointer inserted cannot be changed later on, and the value pointed to it can only be changed after explicitly getting rid of the `const`ness of your pointer. Inserting into it is possible, since adding `const` is always implicitly possible

Comment: With regards to `std::list<int const* const>`, in C++03, it was illegal (undefined behavior), and in C++11, `std::list` and `std::set` are the only containers which allow it.

Comment: And of course, while this is a very good explination of what is going on, it sort of avoids the real question: why the pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Change the `list` to take a pointer to `const`:

```
std::list<const int*> l;
```

Since you had a pointer to `const` for the parameter, taking away its `const`-ness through an implicit conversion wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: It should take a pointer to const, not const pointer, so std::list<const int*> is correct here.

Comment: After reading this (useful short answer), it is a good idea to read dionadar's long and informative answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the typical higher-level "issues" with C++-style compile-time const-correctness type system.

If you want to store `int *` pointers in your list, then you will not be able to add `const int *` pointers to that list (for obvious reasons). This will allso force all your `insert` methods to accept `int *` pointers, not `const int *` pointers.

I understand, that what you really want to express is that `insert` method itself does not change the pointed data (and it doesn't). However, as you can see, `insert` has some far-reaching side-effects - it stores the pointer in a list. This would potentially violate the const-correctenss if `insert` accepted `const int *` pointers.

In other words, it is not enough to consider what `insert` is doing by itself, it is also important to consider what possibilities `insert` opens to other code (in this case - to other code that has access to the same list). And in your case the possibilities it opens would easily allow const-correcness violations in other code if your `insert` quietly accepted `const int *` pointers.

You can, of course, impose your own vision of proper const-correctness in this case by using forceful `const_cast`s. But it won't look pretty.